# Improper implementation of a Mock Router

Tags: angular

UPDATE: Per the accepted answer below I see that I mixed router testing methods. I've updated my code and the tests are passing but I'm getting this warning:

```
WARN LOG: 'Navigation triggered outside Angular zone, did you forget 
to call 'ngZone.run()'?'
```

Here's the code:

```
describe('ItemComponent', () => {
let component: ItemComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<ItemComponent>;
let location: Location;
let router: Router;

beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [
      RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([
        {
          path: 'home',
          component: HomeComponent
        }
      ])
    ],
    declarations: [ItemComponent, HomeComponent],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
  });

  router = TestBed.get(Router);
  location = TestBed.get(Location);
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ItemComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  fixture.detectChanges();
  router.initialNavigation();
});

it('should create', () => {
  expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});

it('should navigate back to home', fakeAsync(() => {
  component.navigateToHome();
  tick();
  expect(location.path()).toBe('/home');
}));
```

I'm getting an error after adding a mock router for my navigation component, here it is:

```
ItemComponent
✗ should create
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'root' of undefined
```

It was passing before I added my 2nd test case that uses the MockRouter.

In my spec file for my item component I have the following:

```
class MockRouter {
  navigateByUrl(params) {}
}

describe('ItemComponent', () => {
  let component: ItemComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ItemComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule],
      declarations: [ItemComponent],
      providers: [{ provide: Router, useClass: MockRouter }]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ItemComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should navigate back to home', () => {
    let router = TestBed.get(MockRouter);
    let spy = spyOn(router, 'navigateByUrl');

    component.navigateToHome();

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['home']);
  });
});
```

Here's the method in my component class:

```
navigateToHome() {
this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
```

}

Did I implement using a Mock Router incorrectly? Thanks for any helpful tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to mock the router if you are importing `RouterTestingModule`. This `import` will do the mocking for you.

Try:

```
describe('NavigationComponent', () => {
  let component: RaNavigationComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<RaNavigationComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule],
      declarations: [RaNavigationComponent],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(RaNavigationComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should navigate back to home', () => {
    let router = TestBed.get(Router);
    let spy = spyOn(router, 'navigateByUrl');

    component.navigateToHome();

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/home');
  });
});
```